# Trigger submit as html5 slider's value changes

Tags: html, slider, range

How do I trigger a submit when the slider's value changes? The captured value in my code determines the width of the svg rectangle. I would like the width to change as I slide the slider without hitting 'submit'. I've used '{{float(x)}}' in a python tornado context.

Tried this so far:

```
<form name="form" oninput="rangeValueDisplay.value=range.value">
Width: <input type="range" name="range" value="100" min="100" max="1000" />
<output name="rangeValueDisplay" for="range">1960</output>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<rect width="{{float(x)}}" height="100"
style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
</svg>
```

A similar question from another user -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540848/autosubmit-html5-range-slider

Comment: Submitting each time the value changes would be unusable, you'd end up submitting the form while the user is dragging the slider.

Comment: makes sense!!! The same can be said of using setInterval right?

Comment: You could clear the interval when the slider changes and then set it again, so you only submit the form after 100ms inactivity or something.

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamic resizing of the rectangle based on the slider value, you can use jQuery:

JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('input[type=range]').change(function() {
        $('rect').attr('width', $(this).val());
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: but it doesn't resize according to the value. Try resliding to a lower value and it doesn't happen.

Comment: that works... but I'd like an auto-submit to happen each time the value changes. That's the reason i quoted the 'python tornado' context.

Comment: I updated the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gahathat/LRarj/1/), but it won't work because you can't submit on jsFiddle. It should work on your own server.